# Cancan's load_and_authorize_resource when resource name is different from model/controller name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resources, cancan

In my app, I have sheets controller, model name is Sheet but my routes are as below

```
routes.rb
 namespace :magazine do
  resources :pages, :controller => "sheets" do
    resources :articles do
     resources :comments
```

so that url will be magazine/page/1/article...

In my Article controller how to call load_and_authorize_resource for sheets so that I can access article of the related sheet.
I tried

```
load_and_authorize_resource :sheet, :class => 'Sheet', :parent => false
load_and_authorize_resource :through => :sheet
```

Cannot access @sheet.articles......

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Either you have:

```
 load_and_authorize_resource :page, :class => 'Sheet', :parent => false
```

And you access your data with `@pages`

Or you replace with:

```
 load_and_authorize_resource :sheet, :class => 'Sheet', :parent => false
```

And you access your data with `@sheets`

---

In ArticlesController, to get both `sheet` and `articles`:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :sheet, :class => 'Sheet'
load_and_authorize_resource :article, :through => :sheet
```

Comment: still the same.....load_and_authorize_resource :sheet, :class => 'Sheet', :parent => false                      load_and_authorize_resource :through => :sheet Does not work

Comment: why do you need `parent` ?

Comment: in which controller are you, waht data do you want?

Comment: I am at Article controller, since my article is associated with sheet, I first load sheet and then :article, :through => :sheet. In Article create action =>                                       @article = @sheet.articles.build(params[:article]) ---- not working